# error from debugger: the program being debugged is not being run

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i have run my application in device but application is crashed and print following message

error from debugger: the program being debugged is not being run.

so please tell me what to do?

my application gonna launch properly but not not debugging **first time** (gonna crash) than from second time i start application work proper without crashing

my application install in device. we can`t debug in device...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing i do when i get that is a Clean All usually solves that. If you don't see the Clean All button right click your Xcode toolbar, customize, and drag the Clean All button to your toolbar from there.

-Check that the provisioning profile installed on your device haven't expired (would see a red dot in the organizer - Window->Organizer).

-Try restarting XCode.

Comment: Or Command-Shift-K for clean all with the default Xcode shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean device? If so then it could mean the device is not launching the application correctly. Make sure your developer profile and everything in the build settings is correctly set. This may sound obvious but also make sure the device is unlocked and open.